# IIS7 .NET x64 aspnet_regiis -i causes class not registered error

Tags: .net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, aspnet-regiis.exe

We are running IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, with websites running on .NET 2.0. The websites work fine except that global themes do not work. I went ahead and tried to do aspnet_regiis -c in the Framework64 directory and got

```
An error has occured: 0x80040154 Class not registered. 
The error indicates that IIS is not installed on the machine. 
Please install IIS before using this tool.
```

If you are wondering, the enabled32bitApps flag is off, so .NET x64 is used.
I went ahead and uninstalled `(aspnet_regiis -u)` and reinstalled (`aspnet_regiis -i`) .net in Framework64 folder successfully. 
Afterwards I got same result trying to run `aspnet_regiis -c`.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: Looks like a COM interop issue.  Are you sure the interop assembly is compiled for 64-bit?  You haven't specified any details of the Web application or its dependencies.  That might help us help you.

Comment: Which interop assembly are you referring to? Our websites dont reference any .COM objects

Comment: I don't know.  You have not specified any details about your application, only an error message that points to COM interop.

Comment: Note that some of your applications assemblies may in fact reference unmanaged code.  For example, some PDF or ADO libraries come to mind.  Help us out by giving us a list of dependencies that your application relies on.

Comment: Why would the application work correctly 100%? The only thing is that asp.net does not recognize is global themes. I guess I gotta figure out what does this -c actually do. It should register client scripts, but I have to see what else it does.

Comment: Prodding for more info again - I assume you migrated from 2003 to 2008 server, correct?  Global themes changed between IIS6 and IIS7, but I have not found a clear answer.  Try turning on all of the IIS6 compatibility features.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517604/asp-net-2-0-global-themes-not-working-on-new-windows-server-2008

Comment: I am running IIS7 on my localmachine and had no problems registering global themes. I am starting to believe things might have been installed in an incorrect order when this box was setup.

Comment: One last comment - Your assumption about 32-bit/64-bit is incorrect.  Just because the OS is 64-bit does not mean both versions of .NET won't be installed.  They will both be there and you can run 32-bit only application pools as necessary.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a easy workaround for this which does not include running the `aspnet_regiis -c` command. Under your default site in IIS, you should already have following directory structure:

```
aspnet_clinet --> system_web --> 2_0_50727
```

All you have to do is copy your themes into  `...\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\Themes` on your file system and then 
create a IIS virtual directory "Themes" in `aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727` which maps to your file system Themes directory.