# aspnet_regiis -c 0x80040154 Class not registered

Tags: iis, windows-8.1, asp.net-2.0, aspnet-regiis.exe

I have a weird issue with windows 8.1 and .NET 2 (yes I have to use it for this project). Running aspnet_regiis -c for .NET 4.5 gives no errors and says it copied the client side files correctly. When I go into the .NET 2 folder it gives this error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -c
Start copying the ASP.NET client script files for this version (2.0.50727).
An error has occurred: 0x80040154 Class not registered

The error indicates that IIS is not installed on the machine. Please install IIS
 before using this tool.
```

I have done some reading and one answer on SO says:

> I have found a easy workaround for this which does not include running
>   the aspnet_regiis -c command. Under your default site in IIS, you
>   should already have following directory structure:
>
> aspnet_clinet --> system_web --> 2_0_50727  All you have to do is copy
>   your themes into ...\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\Themes
>   on your file system and then create a IIS virtual directory "Themes"
>   in aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727 which maps to your file system
>   Themes directory.

Link: [IIS7 .NET x64 aspnet_regiis -i causes class not registered error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119251/iis7-net-x64-aspnet-regiis-i-causes-class-not-registered-error)

I don't know if this is actually a good solution, especially since this seems to be a compatibility issue between .NET 2 and Windows 8.1. Is there another work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

First, let me preface this answer by saying that I don't really know what the command `aspnet_regiis -c` is supposed to do. The [aspnet_regiis documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx) is kind of vague - it says that client side scripts are supposed to be installed, but it doesn't give any information on those scripts.

In any case, when I ran it on an earlier OS (Win 2003 Server), all it did was create some empty directories (and did not actually copy any scripts into them).

This answer resolves the error you are seeing and allows Windows 8.x to do the same as Win 2003 - that is create some empty directories under your web application directory. However, I don't know if that actually allows your application to do what it needs to do.

**Getting to your problem**

The .Net 2 `aspnet_regiis -c` command assumes that the IIS Administration Service is installed. This is a legacy service from IIS 6 that is of course not installed by default in Windows 8.x.

You can install this service by going to *Programs and Features* in the *Control Panel* and enabling the *IIS 6 Management Compatibility* feature, as well as it's sub-items:

[image: Enable IIS 6 Management in Programs and Features]

After you do the above, you should be able to run the command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727> .\aspnet_regiis.exe -c
Start copying the ASP.NET client script files for this version (2.0.50727).
Finished copying the ASP.NET client script files for this version (2.0.50727).
```

As I said before, all this does is create empty folders under your web apps and may or may not actually solve your problem. Just as an example, it will create the following directory structure assuming you have only the default IIS web app:

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727
```

Comment: "as well as it's sub-items:" That fixed it! Thanks